# Thread data sharing

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, data-sharing

I have a thread(A) that produces an object every few seconds,and I have two or more threads(B) that only need to read this object and copy it.

I can not use a Queue, because only one object is created and  must be read by all the threads(B) , if I put the object in the queue, only first thread(B) read the data and the others do not, moreover every few seconds the value is changed by Thread (A) and the Threads (B) read and copy again.

```
T(A)  -- > Obj0
T(B0)  <-- Obj0
T(B1)  <-- Obj0

T(A)  --> Obj1
T(B0)  <-- Obj1
T(B1)  <-- Obj1
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with this FAQ and repost your question -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you implement a topic structure that simply broadcasts messages that get posted to it to the consumer threads that subscribe to it?

Comment: how Observer pattern?